# Dropdown dependente após carregamento de DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Eu tenho no arquivo `Fields.php` o código abaixo, que seleciona a companhia e de acordo com a solicitação irá carregar `divs` com campos especificos para aquela solicitacao. 
Na primeira solicitacao, eu tenho que carregar a Sede e ela é carregada de acordo com o código da companhia selecionada (TT ou PA). Se a companhioa selecionada for TT os dados do `menu dropdown` devem ser 2998 w 2378 se for PA deve ser 9867 e 5678, esses dados estão salvos em uma tabela. 
O problema é que como a `DIV` com os campos são carregados somente após a escolha da solicitação, tanto por `JavaScript/JQuery`, quanto por `VBScript` ou `$_POST` o valor da Companhia não é puxado. Só para deixar claro esse `script` que tenho fuciona para 99% dos casos que pegamos aqui mas geralmente o `dropdown` "filho" e "pai" estão dentro da mesma `div`. Alguma ideia? Tem coisas que são do `Framework` e padronizados, preciso deixar os `scripts` em arquivos diferentes e os `selects` são assim também.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(Company,' - ',Nome) AS Valor, CONCAT(Company,' - ',Nome) AS Texto FROM Company WHERE Pais LIKE '$pais' AND (Company LIKE 'TT%' OR Company LIKE 'PA%') ORDER BY Valor";
new SelectField("company","Company","",260,"onChange=LoadPlant()",$idioma,"line","","mandatory;",$sql,"DB_".$dbPath."Company","show");



$sql = "SELECT Codigo AS Valor, Opcao AS Texto FROM Solicitacao WHERE Pais LIKE '$pais' ORDER BY Valor";
new SelectField("solicitacao","Tipo da Solicitação","",260,"onChange=Solicitcao_OnChange()",$idioma,"line","","mandatory;",$sql,"DB_".$dbPath."Company","show");

$idSolicitacao = "01"; 
echo "<div id=$idSolicitacao>";

$sql = "SELECT Opcao AS Valor, Opcao AS Texto FROM plant_material WHERE Market = 'xxx'";
new SelectField($idSolicitacao."plant","Plant (Material/Destination)","",260,"",$idioma,"line","","mandatory;",$sql,"DB_".$dbPath."Forms_96","show");     


echo "</div>";
```

Em outro arquivo o `LoadPlant.php` tenho

```
$company = utf8_decode($_POST["company"]);

$sql = "SELECT Opcao FROM plant_material WHERE Market = '$company' ORDER BY Opcao";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<option value=''>-</option>";    
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<option value='$rs[Opcao]'>".htmlentities("$rs[Opcao]")."</option>";
}
```

E no arquivo `Function.js` tenho

```
//<<<<< LoadPlant() >>>>>
function LoadPlant()
{   
    var company = $("#company").val();
    var idSolicitacao = $("#Solicitacao").val();

    $.post(
        "Scripts/LoadPlant.php",
        {company:company},
        function(valor)
        {                   
            $("select[name=plant]").html(valor);    
        }
    );
}
```